# Is there a name for a function that tests a set is a subset of another, but is not empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would say $A$ is a subset of $B$ if $A$ contained $(X,Y,Z)$ and $B$ contained $(W,X,Y,Z)$.

But if $A$ contains the null set, and $B$ **something**, (or nothing?) and I still need the result to be false, is there a name for this?

if $F = A \subset B$,

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
\hline
A &B &F(A,B)\\
\hline
 & &False\\
\hline
 &4 &False\\
\hline
3 &&False \\
\hline
3 &3&True \\
\hline
 3&3,4&True \\
\hline
 3,4&3&False \\
\hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-empty subset?  $$\quad\emptyset\subsetneq A\subseteq B$$

Or, equivalently (and mayhap easier to read): $~0\neq A\subseteq B$